# Does the Hubble law make sense?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, redshift, gravitational-redshift

The Hubble law says that if an object is at a distance $r$, it should have a velocity $Hr$ and therefore any light signal from that object will be correspondingly redshifted. However, the light reaching me from the object was emitted a long time ago when the distance was much less than $r$. So why should the signal be redshifted as if it were moving at velocity $Hr$?

Comment: If we see the distant galaxy as it was in the past and we want to calculate the actual distance we should measure the time needed by light to travel to us but in an expanding universe the speed of light towards a distant point (us) is not simply r/c because the expansion of the universe makes a countereffect. Something like but not exactly like moving on an escalator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hubble constant relates the proper distance and the rate of change of that proper distance with respect to cosmological epoch.

Proper distance is the distance to an object at the current cosmological epoch, which you have labelled as $r$, and not its distance when the light was emitted.

You correctly point out that the estimated distance based on light travel time, is not the proper distance, but you got the error the wrong way around. What is commonly referred to as the "distance" to a cosmological object is actually the one based on the light travel time and is smaller than the proper distance because of the universal expansion.

As a result, any straight line relationship between redshift and light travel time distance only works in our cosmological back yard as it were.

At greater distances, the straight line curves and in addition one has to contend with the fact that the Hubble constant is not a constant.

Why $v = H_0 r$ for a uniform expansion is easily established by drawing a sequence of dots on a piece of paper, allowing the space between the dots to expand uniformly, and then asking what is the relationship between the relative velocity and separation of any of the dots at a particular time.

Comment: So is the redshift due to the velocity of the receding galaxy or due to the stretching of space as the light travels to us?

Comment: It becomes unhelpful to think of it as a velocity as the "relative velocities" become large. Better to think of it as the wavelength of the light being stretched as it travels to us. @EricDavidKramer

Answer (score 1):

Hubble Law works on Astronomical Scale. It works very Best at very very far off galaxies at astronomical scale. Even while talking about Andromeda galaxy which is 2.537 million light-years away we don't much talk about Hubble's law.precisely because a lot of other parameters such as gravity tend to dominate.

Galaxy out there in space which is some billion or so light-years away, while light coming from these sources takes billion years to come, and therefore due to expansion of the universe the light as a whole gets red-shifted.

Space is expanding and that galaxies are moving away from the Earth at velocities proportional to their distance therefore wavelength gets expanded and therefore appears redshifted.
The velocity of the galaxies has been determined by their Redshift, a shift of the light they emit to the red end of the spectrum.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Erik Thank You for your Question.

Disclaimer:  I am new to Physics Stacks learning my way on the job.

To answer your question.  No. Hubble's law does not make sense.  We observed that objects are moving away faster than they should; so Hubble's law says space is growing larger.

Then again.. I also do not think Time Dilation makes sense; But I vehemently believe that the faster we travel through space the slower we travel through Time.

In fact this is why I have an issue with the Hubble Law.  Almost everyone agrees and understands that objects very far away are not in the position they are observed solely because of the point you made "the light reaching me from the object was emitted a long time ago when the distance was much less than r." This is reversed (The object has moved further away during the time it took the photon to reach earth) but I follow your point. However, we rarely hear about the impact Time Dilation (from Earth's Velocity) has on Hubble's Law.

In short..  Hubble did not solely observe objects moving forward through space.  He also observed, quite possibly unknowingly, objects moving forward through time as well.  The further away you look... The further into the future an object travels through time(Its future; within our past.. Earth's)...  This is profound.  This is material.  Looking at objects close by show how time dilation is immaterial because the photons do not take large amounts of time to arrive at our Earth orbiting satellite (Hubble).

But looking further away, lets say 300 Megaparsecs,  That object moves forward for two completely different reasons 1) The photon takes approximately one billion years to arrive on earth and yes that object moves forward through space during that time; but it also  2) Moved forward through time by approximately 3,710 years... That is because of Time Dilation caused from the earth moving through space at 818,965 meters per second (stacking our movement through the solar system, it's movement through the galaxy, and the Milky Way's movement through the universe).

Using the following Time Dilation Formula:

[image]

Earths Time is Dilated .9999962687 seconds per second from its velocity through the universe; and because there are a lot more seconds being dilated when observing far away objects; these objects(300 Mpc) have also moved further through space for an additional 3,710 years.  At an inch per hour that is not a material number.  But we are talking about objects flying around at 800 Thousand Meters per Second; and there are 31,536,000 seconds in one year; or 116,998,560,000 seconds in 3710 years; which extrapolates to an additional 9,359,884,800,000,000 (Quadrillions) meters of distance that object has traveled further away; before the moment the photon hits Hubble's mirror.

Look at that object a few years later.  It most definitely should look a lot further away. Does that mean space is expanding?  Like you I'm trying to figure that one out. Requesting some data on this one and hope to have more information this week.

I loved your question!

Comment: Hubble's Law says space expands 70 km/s - per Mpc ...  In the above we are talking about distances of 300 Mpc and meters not km... Apples to Apples  - Hubble is saying space expands at 70,000 meters per second per Mpc or 21 Million Meters per 300 Mpc  each second.   In a one year time that equates to approximately 662,256,000,000,000 (Trillions) Meters per year -   I don't have all of the research yet but it is more than plausible to suggest that with these numbers -   Space is not expanding (its contracting) once one considers the impact of time dilation.

Comment: However this is based on the observation at a one year frequency and shows us it is possible that we see photons and measure the candles they originate from as they are moving through both time and space.    If the frequency of observation (measurements) is  14.133 years then the universe is actually static.  If the frequency exceeds 14.133 years then the universe is expanding.   For the sake of being precise I want to look at all the data and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You took the question in an interesting direction. Time is relative. Any observer will always move through his/her proper time at the same rate, no matter how fast they move. However, using the proper time of the lab frame, the lab time will always be larger than the observer's proper time. It does not make sense to say how far you move through time without saying whose clock you are referring to.

Comment: Thank You Eric - I am looking at the measurements.  The relativistic values are within Sigma 9 - The Hubble Values are within Sigma 3 - Wavelength of light is an important variable as this is perversely manipulated by time dilation.   Proper Time fails us in this aspect so I appreciate your pointing out the laboratory time variance is larger.   As such Frequency is inversely proportional to a decrease in Wavelength which is perturbed at extreme distance.

Comment: I am referring to Earth's clock...  At Hubble Lens.